# Arrow head halfway along parametric plot

Tags: plotting, graphics, color

I have a problem with putting arrowheads on my parametric plot, I have looked through the various examples on here, which all work fine, but when I replace it with the code for my parametric plot, I get the error:

Arrow setbacks VertexColors -> Automatic should be a number or pair of numbers.

For example,

This code works to put an arrow halfway along a plot which is what i would like to do on my own plot

```
    ClearAll[f, x, data];
    f[x_] := x^2;
    data = Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, -10, 10, 0.1}];
    p0 = ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, Joined -> True, 
       PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}];


    p0 /. Line[x_] :> {Arrowheads[{0,0.1,0}], Arrow[x]}
```

and produces

[image]

However, when i change it over to my plot:

```
   p0 = ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {t, 0, pt[[1]]}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
   PlotRange -> {{-0.8, 0.8}, {-0.8, 0.8}}, 
   ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, t}, Hue[0.7*t]], Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {{"y/λ", None}, {"x/λ", 
      HoldForm["f" = Fi]}}, 
   GridLines -> {{0.4, 0, -0.4}, {-0.4, 0, 0.4}}, 
   FrameTicksStyle -> Thick, 
   FrameTicks -> {{{-0.8, -0.4, 0, 0.4, 0.8}, 
      None}, {{-0.8, -0.4, 0, 0.4, 0.8}, None}}, 
   GridLinesStyle -> Opacity[0.5], Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 300, 
   PlotRangePadding -> None, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 18}, 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic];


   p0 /. Line[x_, y_] :> {Arrowheads[{0, 0.1, 0}], Arrow[x, y]}
```

i get this:

[image]

For the life of me i can't figure this out, the plot appears but is covered in the dreaded red box with the error message i gave at the top of the page.

Comment: The complete code has not been provided.  For instance, `x`, `y`, and `pt` are undefined.  Hence, `ParametricPlot` fails.

Comment: It is defined in my code, those come from an NDS solve of four coupled differential equations, i didn't include the whole thing because it's a big block of work. You can replace x and y with Cos[t] and Sin[t] and pt[[1]] with 2Pi and you still get the same error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The real problem your are having is the way `GraphicsComplex` uses `VertexColors`. In short, your parametric plot with colors produces something like this

```
Graphics[GraphicsComplex[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 1}},
  {Line[{1, 2, 3}, VertexColors -> Automatic]}, 
  VertexColors -> {Yellow, Blue, Green}
  ]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that at the end of `Line` it says `VertexColors -> Automatic` which states that it uses the vertex color definition that is given at the end of `GraphicsComplex`.

Just replacing `Line` with `Arrow` will therefore not work and you will get an error message because `Arrow` does not take a `VertexColors` option.

In fact, `Arrow` cannot be used with `VertexColors` at all. Fortunately, `Arrow` cannot take only points as arguments, but `Lines` primitives itself. Therefore, one solution to your problem is

```
p0 = ParametricPlot[{t, t^2}, {t, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
  PlotRange -> {{-0.8, 0.8}, {-0.8, 0.8}}, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, t}, Hue[0.7*t]], Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {{"y/\[Lambda]", None}, {"x/\[Lambda]", 
     HoldForm["f" = Fi]}}, 
  GridLines -> {{0.4, 0, -0.4}, {-0.4, 0, 0.4}}, 
  FrameTicksStyle -> Thick, 
  FrameTicks -> {{{-0.8, -0.4, 0, 0.4, 0.8}, 
     None}, {{-0.8, -0.4, 0, 0.4, 0.8}, None}}, 
  GridLinesStyle -> Opacity[0.5], Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 300, 
  PlotRangePadding -> None, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 18}, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic]

p0 /. l_Line :> {Arrowheads[{0, 0.1, 0}], Arrow[l]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Beautiful mate thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

In the absence of definitions for `x`, `y`, and `pt`, set

```
 x = t^2; y = t^3;
```

and replace `p[[1]]` by `1` for specificity.  Then an arrow is obtained by replacing the last line of the code by

```
(p0 // Normal) /. Line[x_] :> {Arrowheads[{0, 0.1, 0}], Arrow[x]}
```

[image]

`Normal` is needed to convert `GraphicsComplex` to `Line`.

Comment: Thank you, this works nicely, however, the Hue color function of the line has been lost (or overwritten?).

Comment: @Colin  It has been lost but can be recovered with a little work.  Too late for me to do so now, however.

Comment: No worries thanks for your work, if anyone could come up with a work around to get the color function working again i'd be very greatfull :)